# Immediate reward in a continuous time Markov decision process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process

I don't have much background in MDPs but I was reading a text in which I came across the following which I am finding difficult to understand. Consider a Markov decision process with state space $S$ where the only action possible for state $s=0$ is $a=0$ and the reward on completing the action is $r_a$ and the task time is exponentially distributed with rate $\mu_a$. Then as per the model in question(the details of which I have not included here) there exists a finite uniformization constant $q$ for the CTMC. Then the text claims that the
the immediate reward obtained when action $a=0$ is chosen in state $s=0$ is
$$r(0,0)=r_a\frac{\mu_a}{q}$$
I dont understand how this is obtained. I know what is uniformization of a CTMC but I don't understand how to relate it to the reward. How can the reward be less than $r_a$? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi: If you give the book title, some people might have it and can look at the section in more detail.

Comment: Its from this paper:https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0377221720307104

Comment: Hi: Thanks and it looks interesting ( I was majored in OR in undergrad ) but I don't have time to look at it currently. I still think it might increase the chances of getting a response. Good luck.